# Microsoft Graph API, can I filter List Items

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I can get all items in a list with:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SiteID}/lists/{ListID}/items](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BSiteID%7D/lists/%7BListID%7D/items)

I can get a specific item in a list with:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{SiteID}/lists/{ListID}/items/{ItemID}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7BSiteID%7D/lists/%7BListID%7D/items/%7BItemID%7D)

But I have to KNOW the ItemID to interact with that specific item.

Is there no way to use $search or $filter on list items to find an item by one of my actual column values, like $filter=Title eq 'whatever', to then be able to pull the ItemID for that item so I can update values for it?

Or do I just have to download the entire list and filter it myself?  Seems inefficient though if it were to be a large list.

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK, the columns that are created for lists are not indexed, so they are not searchable or filterable. You can simply get the items with fields(Columns) using this http call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}/lists/{listid}/items?$expand=fields` and then filter it on your end by writing code.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The filtering can be allowed by adding the header `Prefer: HonorNonIndexedQueriesWarningMayFailRandomly`.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items?$expand=fields&filter=fields/Title eq 'whatever'
```

One disadvantage is that such queries can fail on large lists

Comment: Ta - this works perfectly and the problem has been bugging me for years!

Comment: Rhetorical question, but how can anyone confidently implement anything that includes ‘may fail randomly’ in its name?